# How to make navigation bar scroll with the page?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

How do i make my navigation bar scroll down together with the page? I have found some answers here but I'm having a hard time cause the code for my navigation bar is in another file and I just used `<?php include ("includes/navbar.php"); ?>` to incorporate it to my other pages. Here are my codes so far: What I'm planning to do is if I scroll my page down the navigation bar will be on top of the page

**Navigation**

```
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <!-- Button for smallest screens -->
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse"><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span></button>
            <!--<a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">
            <img src="assets/images/logo.png" alt="Techro HTML5 template"></a>-->
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right mainNav">
                <li class="c1 active"><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
                <li class="c1"><a href="profile.php">Profile</a></li>
                <li class="c1"><a href="games.php">Games</a></li>
                <li class="c1"><a href="#">Top Players</a></li>                     
                <li class="c1"><a href="about.php">About</a></li>                   
                <li class="c1 dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Settings <b class="caret"></b></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a data-toggle="modal" data-target='#change'>Change Password</a></li>
                        <li><a href="../logout.php">Logout</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <!--/.nav-collapse -->
    </div>

    <!--MODAL-->
        <?php include("includes/changepass.php");?>
    <!--END MODAL-->


</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > li.c1 a{
color: #00A8FF;
}

.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > li.c1 a:hover, .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > li.c1.active a{
color:#fff;
background: #00A8FF;
}
```

**JS**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {

      $(window).scroll(function () {
          console.log($(window).scrollTop())
        if ($(window).scrollTop() > 280) {
          $('.navbar').addClass('navbar-fixed');
        }
        if ($(window).scrollTop() < 281) {
          $('.navbar').removeClass('navbar-fixed');
        }
      });
    });
</script>
```

**Here's how my page looks**

[image]

Comment: Did you try adding the class [navbar-fixed-top](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar-fixed-top) to your `nav` ul?

Comment: I added something cause I forgot to say that there's a div.

Comment: if i try putting navbar-fixed-top, it immediately attached itself to the top. Which is not I'm trying to do.

Comment: Then please provide a simple [JSFiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net/) and elaborate more about what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be you are looking for this. View in fullscreen

You should add `$('.navbar').addClass('navbar-fixed-top');`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(window).scroll(function() {
    console.log($(window).scrollTop())
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > 280) {
      $('.navbar').addClass('navbar-fixed-top');
    }
    if ($(window).scrollTop() < 281) {
      $('.navbar').removeClass('navbar-fixed-top');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > li.c1 a {
  color: #00A8FF;
}
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > li.c1 a:hover,
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > li.c1.active a {
  color: #fff;
  background: #00A8FF;
}
.dummy-div {
  background: black;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="dummy-div">

</div>
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <!-- Button for smallest screens -->
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse"><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <!--<a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">
            <img src="assets/images/logo.png" alt="Techro HTML5 template"></a>-->
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right mainNav">
        <li class="c1 active"><a href="index.php">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="c1"><a href="profile.php">Profile</a>
        </li>
        <li class="c1"><a href="games.php">Games</a>
        </li>
        <li class="c1"><a href="#">Top Players</a>
        </li>
        <li class="c1"><a href="about.php">About</a>
        </li>
        <li class="c1 dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Settings <b class="caret"></b></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a data-toggle="modal" data-target='#change'>Change Password</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="../logout.php">Logout</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <!--/.nav-collapse -->
  </div>

  <!--MODAL-->
  <?php include( "includes/changepass.php");?>
  <!--END MODAL-->


</div>
<div style="height: 2000px;">
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: sir this works but I don't understand why it wont work if I wont use the link version of the bootstrap.min.css, bootstrap.min.js, jquery.min.js

Comment: @KaelJasper Do you have css/js local files ? if its not working, check console for any errors. Let me know after trying. Since this is a bootstrap nav, it require all the above plugins I have added. jquery must place at the very top.

Comment: my bad, it actually worked. My dropbox haven't sync the updates I made.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using BootStrap, please add the following class to your `<nav>` element:

```
navbar-fixed-top
```

Eg:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding `position:fixed` to the CSS for `.navbar.navbar-inverse`?